# How to track clicks on each blog posts in blogger using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, blogger, event-tracking

I configured GA to my blog. **I want to track the clicks on each blogpost**. i dont know where i have to insert event tracking code in my blog for tracking clicks on each blogposts.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new HTML widget and paste your code in it. The widgets appear on home page as well as all the posts. It's important that GA code should be there on all pages.